# Screwed up my bash prompt, what happened?

Tags: bash, prompt

I just thought I might get version information about the current bash by entering

```
bash -v
```

That brought many lines of code to stdout and left me with a line that appears right above my usual promt

```
printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"
[foo@bar path]$
```

I think I have a tiny clue what this might be (the code that renders how the prompt looks like), but I have no idea whatsoever how to get rid of this. Who does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply type `exit` to get out of the new `bash` shell you invoked.

**Explanation**

The `-v` option doesn't do what you think. From `bash(1)`:

> -v     Display  readline variable names and values in such a way
>                        that they can be re-read.

So what your command does is start another `bash` shell with the `-v` option that prints the various variable names you see in your output.

What you want is

```
bash --version
```

**Update**

Since the OP [commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127501/screwed-up-my-bash-prompt-what-happened/127502?noredirect=1#comment204235_127502) that this sounds too much like a "restart your system" kind of answer, here's an alternative way:

Disable the `-v` option by issuing

```
set +v
```

Note, though, that this will leave you in the child shell you forked earlier by calling `bash`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the job. I was afraid this might stay...

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel Please accept the answer then so that everyone can see this question is done.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Yeah, sorry for not having accepted this earlier. But I posed this question yesterday before I went to bed. Now I saw the answer (which helped me) and I wanted to accept it, but would have had to wait another 6 minutes before I could accept. So I postponed accepting to the next day. I apologize.

Comment: I like this answer because it's just like 99% of all IT problem solving advices: "Restart your system!" :-)

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel Please see the update :)